# Recovering hazard rate for interacted Poisson model in R

Tags: r, poisson-regression, hazard

I am implementing the Wooldridge Two Way Mundlak regression and have an interacted model like so:

```
library(fixest)
reg = fepois(y ~ post_treatment:i(var1,var2,ref=0, ref2=0)|idvar+timevar, cluster="idvar", data=regdata)
```

And I'd like to recover the hazard rate impact of `post_treatment`, including standard errors, but I can't figure out how to do it building from `marginaleffects::avg_slopes`. Is there a way to do it through this or another approach?